# T-SQL : using variable in different database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to find a way to use a declared variable's result from one database to be used in a different database:

For example:

```
USE DB1
GO

DECLARE @d DATETIME

SELECT TOP 1 @d = Date 
FROM DateDB
 
USE DB2
GO

PRINT @d
```

Error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@d"

Not sure if it is possible, so figured Id ask S.O. after Googling (Perhaps incorrectly) for the last 45 minutes.

Comment: Variables exist for the duration of the batch, you are executing two separate batches. If you want to persist data over multiple batches use a table.

Comment: @Stu - That is it brothaman - If you want to change that comment into an answer, Ill mark it as such - Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables only exist for the lifetime of a *single* batch.

In SSMS, the `GO` keyword (assuming it hasn't been altered in the settings) separates batches.

The statements following `GO` are a new separate batch; to persist data you will need to store it - you can create a table in TempDB for such a purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The `go` keyword is treated as a batch separator by SQL Server Management Studio and sqlcmd. It indicates the start of a new batch, and each new batch has its own variables.

However, there is a convenient storage for variables between databases in a single session: session storage. These context variables persist for the life of the session and can be referenced in multiple batches.

Use the [sp_set_session_context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system procedure to set a session context variable. Use the [SESSION_CONTEXT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to retrieve the session context variables.

For example:

```
USE DB1
GO

DECLARE @d DATETIME

SELECT @d = '1/1/2022'

PRINT @d
 
EXEC sp_set_session_context @key = N'MyDate', @value = @d

USE DB2
GO

DECLARE @d DATETIME
SELECT @d = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'MyDate') AS DATETIME)
PRINT @d
```

Output:

```
Jan  1 2022 12:00AM
Jan  1 2022 12:00AM
```

If you need to remember a variable across multiple *sessions*, then you must save the variable to a persistent storage like a tempdb table or global temporary ##Table.

For example, an initialization batch could save a date value in a tempdb table called `tempdb..MyVariables` column `MyDate`. Later sessions processing this information could refer to the value in this table column. A final cleanup session could remove the table completely.

Answer (score 1):

You Should specify the whole name with schema

for example

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.MyTable
```